# nmcli for vpn pptp connection from command line . centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, nmcli

**i use to connection vpn from command line**

> my os centos 7
>
> how i can install it org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
>
> if i start connection

```
[root@vps4910 ~]# nmcli connection up VPN_2
    Error: Connection activation failed: The VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' was not installed.
    [root@vps4910 ~]#
```

Comment: `The VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' was not installed.` Just install what it says.

Comment: how i can install it org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp

Comment: `sudo yum install NetworkManager-pptp` and make sure you have epel repo enabled.

Comment: Error: Unable to find a match: NetworkManager-pptp

Comment: do this first `yum install epel-release`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by @annahri

> just install this

```
yum install epel-release
sudo yum install NetworkManager-pptp
```